# .replace() contententeditable negative regex

Tags: javascript, typescript, replace, contenteditable

I'm trying to replace words in my contenteditable if they are not the words "sample" or "test". If they are not those words, I want to color them blue in my contenteditable text box. Right now the regex matches everything and colors everything blue. It works with regex's that do not have the negation or negative lookahead in front of it. Any ideas? Please any advice or suggestions on how to accomplish this would help.

```
 if(e.keyCode == 32){ 
    var text2 = document.getElementById("editor");
    var text = document.getElementById("editor").innerHTML;
    let regexp = /^(?:(?!\b(sample|test)).)*$/g
    var newText = text.replace(regexp, function(g){
      return "<span class='colorblue'>"+g+"</span>";
    });
    document.getElementById("editor").innerHTML = newText;
    var elem = document.getElementById('editor2');
    this.caretAtEnd(text2);
    
}
```

Comment: I think it would be more efficient (not to mention an easier regex) to turn the whole thing blue and then replace "sample" and "test" with a different color.

Comment: yeah i agree. I'm making a text box and trying to make it as so "errors" in this example will be highlighted in blue. So if I do it default blue it looks weird bc its always blue while typing

Comment: You could do it one word at a time by splitting on the boundary first, and if you wanted it dynamic just check on keyup.